# Custom product order e-commerce site development

Tags: woocommerce

I am working on a eCommerce site. My client wants to develop site like this http://lanyardpeople.co.uk. Where someone can order a product and he can customize the product option. All the options will be arranged in several tabs.

I tried to do it in woocommerce but it is not well documented and very hard to understand their API.

Please suggest me with any other eCommerce software with that requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you will succeed searching for a ready made solution. WooCommerce is an extremely good free shopping cart solution and I would stick with that. Then I would use some extension like WooCommerce Product Add-Ons AND hire a developer that would do the fancy part. You won't get away without custom development here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have also used the product add-on.